# Angular 4: Chat application - Receiving messages from the server

Tags: angular, signalr

I am trying to build a new chat application in Angular4. I am able to send the messages using POST. Now I am working on the receiving part. I did some research and found out that some of them used Signalr/long polling/websocket/socket.io. 
I tried POC for all of them but couldn't able to come to a decision.

Comment: This really isn't a question, but rather a statement of your indecision.  Long polling is an older approach than web sockets.  Furthermore, it is considerably less efficient in that it uses the standard request/response/disconnect model whereas web  sockets can send a response to a connected client(s) without being requested to do such (e.g. - when an update to the chat room is needed).

Comment: Yes. Even I am not inclined towards long polling. What is your opinion on signalR